# Nginx front apache then

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, http, https

I had only owncloud running (http and https with apache2) in my network, but now I want host another website.
https was working without warning "Your connection is not secure"

So for this I have installed another server with nginx on which I want to set SSL with my STAR_mydomain_com.crt and _mydomain_com.key I was using on apache2.

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name cloud.mydomain.com;

error_log /var/log/nginx/cloud.access.log;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/STAR_mydomain_com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/_mydomain_com.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # dont use SSLv3 ref: POODLE

location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

    proxy_redirect off;
}}
```

But now I get the message :
"Your connection is not secure"

I don't understand why

Any explanation why?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add the intermediate certificates in your ssl_certificates file. In Apache there is a separate option for intermediate certificates while in nginx there is none. Instead you have to put all intermediate certificates in your ssl_certificates file, right after your own certificate. (See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750890/nginx-install-intermediate-certificate))

---

Original Post:

Die you change the Server Name when switching to nginx?

Certificates are only valid for a certain DNS name.

Usually there is more information in the "Your connection Is not secure"-dialog like "Certificate is only valid for xzy.mydomain.com", that information could help us to resolve your problem.

Comment: No it was before _cloud.mydomain.com_ and it is still _cloud.mydomain.com_ now using the same wildcard.mydomain_com.crt and wildcard_mydomain_com.key that I was using previously without nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Try "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;"

Comment: Also a more specific error message would really help.

Comment: I added X-Frowarded-Porto in my but still not working
So the web browser error is **SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER**

Comment: From which CA did you get your certificate?

Comment: Did you include all intermediate certs?

Comment: I got Comodo ca

Comment: what do you mean buy intermediate certs ?

Comment: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/comodo/Knowledgebase/Article/View/250/17/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/333178)

Comment: In Apache you have "the option SSLCertificateChainFile" for including the intermediate certificates, while nginx doesn't have this option requiring you to put the intermediate certificates in your ssl_certificate file. (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750890/nginx-install-intermediate-certificate)

Comment: @kasperd I know this it not an answer but I couldn't post an answer because of my reputation. Sometimes it is just not possible to provide answers without asking for further informations, I am sorry.

Comment: Thanks you for your help guys it was the chain file that was missing.